# How to find a shortcut's intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

When I long click on Audible (an app for e-book listening) it has an option **My Library** which takes me straight to the Library section of the app. I can hold and drag it out onto the home screen, but the name and icon is fixed as per the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvvEP.jpg).

In order to customize it I am using [Shortcut Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker), but I cannot find the proper link to Audible's **My Library** anywhere, so I've come to the conclusion that I probably need to edit the [intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgACR.jpg).

The good news is that we know it's possible to create a shortcut to **My Library**, but the bad news is that I'm too stupid to figure out how.

Comment: If you are an Android app developer, and you have Android Studio, examine Logcat when you launch that "My Library" shortcut. Android logs the details of started activities, including the core contents of the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am just a normal Android user. I don't know why the .xml got removed, I got it using an APK analyzer app.

Comment: "I don't know why the .xml got removed" -- I doubt that Audible has licensed that file for public distribution by arbitrary people.

Comment: @CommonsWare Right. So with regards to setting the correct intent in Shortcut Maker, short of going dev mode, can you offer any advice as to how to locate the correct input?

Comment: I have never used Shortcut Maker. And, this site is for programming questions. Perhaps Shortcut Maker has a user community that could assist you.